# How do you add a PROTO node programmatically in Webots?

Tags: python, webots

Using a Supervisor controller, is it possible to programmatically add Robot nodes to a running simulation which are defined in .proto files?

I tried using [importMFNode](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab-language=python#wb_supervisor_field_import_mf_node), but it looks like it only supports `.wbo` or `.wrl` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [importMFNodeFromString](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab-language=python#wb_supervisor_field_import_mf_node_from_string) like this:

```py
from controller import Supervisor

supervisor = Supervisor()
children = supervisor.getRoot().getField('children')
children.importMFNodeFromString(-1, 'Nao { translation 0.1 0.334 -0.2 }')
```

That will add a [Nao](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/nao) robot with the specified translation at the bottom of the scene tree. You may also specify the rotation and other parameters of the Nao PROTO.